# Folder-by-type or Folder-by-feature

Tags: project-structure, packages

I make use of an AngularJS style guide. Within this guide there is a style called `folder-by-feature`, instead of `folder-by-type`, and I'm actually curious what's the best approach (in this example for Java)

Let's say I have an application where I can retrieve Users & Pets, using services, controllers, repositories and ofcourse domain objects.

Taking the folder-by-..... styles, we have two options for our packaging structure:

**1. Folder-by-type**

```
com.example
├── domain
│    ├── User.java
│    └── Pet.java
├── controllers
│    ├── UserController.java
│    └── PetController.java
├── repositories
│    ├── UserRepository.java
│    └── PetRepository.java
├── services
│    ├── UserService.java
│    └── PetService.java
│   // and everything else in the project
└── MyApplication.java
```

**2. Folder-by-feature**

```
com.example
├── pet
│    ├── Pet.java
│    ├── PetController.java
│    ├── PetRepository.java
│    └── PetService.java
├── user
│    ├── User.java
│    ├── UserController.java
│    ├── UserRepository.java
│    └── UserService.java
│   // and everything else in the project
└── MyApplication.java
```

***What would be a good approach, and what are the arguments to do so?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does everyone put controllers in one folder and views in another?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310833/why-does-everyone-put-controllers-in-one-folder-and-views-in-another)

Comment: @RubberDuck this question seems to me that it's specifically in the context of Spring. Here the package naming can be used in favour of Spring's features. And that's what OP is asking about.

Comment: I don't know @Laiv. Does the language/framework really affect the answer? Regardless, the other question is certainly relevant.

Comment: @Laiv I removed Spring from the question, because I think this question represents a general problem.

Comment: Then I have to edit my answer. And yest, it's a possible duplicate

Comment: I do think the duplicate is not correct however, simply because in the other question they're talking about asp.net & talking about views/controllers while I want to make this question as general as possible. Java is just there as an example language, and the controller/services/repositories are also just examples of 'types'.

Comment: In esence, it's the same problem. And due to you have removed the mentions to the language and framework, you have also removed any possible difference in the answers.

Comment: I never understood the benefit of folder-by-type. If i'm working on a ticket pertaining to the Pet feature, I would probably benefit from locality of `Pet`, the controller, the repository, and the service. In what situation would I ever need all controllers, but non of the views, repos or services?

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned that packages in Java aren't just folders; they also affect access for the contained classes.  For this reason, package-by-layer/type can actually provide some semantic value in Java.

Comment: current summary: 3 statements for "per feature", 0 for "by type". To bad that many web frameworks have the convention default "by type"

Answer (score 108, accepted):

## Folder-by-type only works on small-scale projects. Folder-by-feature is superior in the majority of cases.

Folder-by-type is ok when you only have a small number of files (under 10 per type, let's say). As soon as you get multiple components in your project, all with multiple files of the same type, it gets very hard to find the actual file you are looking for.

Therefore, folder-by-feature is better due to its scalability. However, if you use folder-by-feature, you end up losing information about the type of component a file represents (because it's no longer in a `controller` folder, let's say), so this too becomes confusing. There are 2 simple solutions for this.

First, you can abide by common naming conventions that imply its type in the file name. For example, John Papa's popular [AngularJS style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y120) has the following:

> ### Naming Guidelines
>
> - Use consistent names for all components following a pattern that describes the component's feature then (optionally) its type. My recommended pattern is `feature.type.js`. There are 2 names for most assets:
>
>   - the file name (`avengers.controller.js`)
>   - the registered component name with Angular (`AvengersController`)

Second, you can combine folder-by-type and folder-by-feature styles into folder-by-feature-by-type:

```
com.example
├── pet
|   ├── Controllers
│   |   ├── PetController1.java
|   |   └── PetController2.java
|   └── Services
│       ├── PetService1.java
│       └── PetService2.java
├── user
|   ├── Controllers
│   |   ├── UserController1.java
│   |   └── UserController2.java
|   └── Services
│       ├── UserService1.java
│       └── UserService2.java
```

Comment: The johnpapa style guide was exactly the one I was fakking about :-)

Comment: Some times (oftener than we think) we add too complexity to things that were supposed to be easy. Naming and packaging are some of these things. The best advice is keep it simple. Mixing both have either the advantages and the disadvantages of both approaches.

Comment: @Laiv In the example I gave I agree its overkill, but in most of my real business cases where each type-folder can easily have 10-20 files I think its very useful because the overall feature-folder would have on the order of 50 files otherwise.

Comment: fakking, thanks iPhone auto-correct! I meant 'talking'.

Comment: I agreed :-). Just pointing to the fact that abusing of subpackages may go to the detriment of the folder-by-feature.

Comment: By the way, I chose this as accepted answer because it re-uses my folder structure, actually answering between Option 1 / 2. David also gives a little extra by talking about the combination of the two options.

Comment: No need to explain why :-). Not allways the answer you find more useful is the most voted. I also agreed with David.

Comment: And what about things common to more than one domain (ex: Photo class  common to Pet and User)?

Comment: @Chaotic This example is too trivial to start talking specifics, but in such cases where you have pieces that are used across multiple components, then that should probably be a component of its own that other components depend on.

Comment: why do we need two controllers per model?   IMHO, i don't think that we need folder by feature + type simply because usually its one model - one class of per type.

Answer (score 34):

This really has nothing to do with the technology in question, unless you use a framework that forces folder-by-type on you as part of a convention-over-configuration approach.

Personally, I am strongly of the opinion, that folder-by-feature is far superior and should be used everywhere as much as possible. It groups together classes that actually work together, whereas folder-by-type just duplicates something that is usually already present in the class name.

Comment: I would add that in folder-by-feature makes easier to play with classes and methods scopes (protected, package,...).

Comment: For smaller projects you may only have one feature.  It is much easier to organize by type in that scenario.

Comment: As an example, **Grails** does force folder-by-type for your domains, controllers, services, etc.

Answer (score 29):

Working with *packages-by-feature* stands out in **high modularity and cohesion**. It allows us to play with the components' scope. For example, we can use the [access modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers) to enforce [LoD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and the [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) for integrations or/and extensions.

Other reasons are:

- Easier code navigation
- A higher level of abstraction
- Minimize scopes (bounding contexts)
- Vertical modularization

*Folder-by-layer* puts [too much emphasis on the implementation details](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2011/09/30/Screaming-Architecture.html), (as @David mentioned) which doesn't tells too much about the application we are working on. Unlike *package-by-feature*, *package-by-layer* encourage horizontal modularization. This sort of modularization makes working with cross-cutting components hard and tedious.

Finally, there's a 3rd option. *Package by component* which, in Uncle Bob's words, is aligned with his [package principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_principles). If Uncle's Bob opinion matters or not, I leave it to you to decide. I find it interesting since this convention is aligned with his Clean Architecture, which I like.